# Checking script with --login-path in Monit gives ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, bash, monit

I’m trying to check some rows in MySQL database via “check program”, but I always get the error message "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

Needless to say that the script works smooth when called from command line.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(mysql --login-path=client -e "USE *db here*; \
                                     SELECT * FROM *table here* \
                                     FROM *db here* b \ );
[...]

*if data ok* exit 0, else exit 1;
```

‌
Monit code:

```
check program images with path /root/scripts/check_images
  every 144 cycles
  if status != 0 then alert


# mysql_config_editor print --all
[client]
user = <dbuser>
password = *****
host = localhost
```

‌
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you restarted once you have made changes in the file.

Comment: Yes, checked syntax with `monit -t` and restarted with `monit reload`

Comment: kindly login directly in mysql by using the credentials and let me know, to check whether there is issue with the credentials.

Comment: Direct login with the credetials of the login path worls fine. Executing the script on command line works also fine, the only thing that doesn't work is when the script is checked by monit... No idea where the problem is. The script is also in bash environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-Posting from [Monit Bug Tracker](https://bitbucket.org/tildeslash/monit/issues/823/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user).

It is about the missing environment inside the executed script. `mysql` uses `$HOME` to determine the place of the `.mylogin.cnf` file.

The final solution is as simple as:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export HOME='/root/'
data=$(mysql -e "SELECT CURRENT_USER()");
state=$?

echo "$data"

exit $state
```

Comment: The line "export HOME='/root/'" did it, thank you very much!